# Failed installation of spaCy on Windows with anaconda

Tags: python, window, spacy

I'm trying to install spaCy with anaconda on a Windows Server. First I created a new environment (in anaconda prompt):

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda

activate  py36

pip install -U spacy
```

And then I started receiving the folioing errors (quite a lot):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: > "Microsoft VIsual c++ 14.0 is required". Did you install it?

Comment: sure, but it still crashes :(